# Is it possible to have a two-column layout in a bookdown::word_document2 document?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, docx, bookdown

I am knitting from RMarkdown to .docx using `bookdown::word_document2` as the output format.

I want to have a section in my document that features two columns. Is this possible?

I know this is possible with the `officedown::rdocx_document` output format, but I cannot use that due to other limitations (it will not allow me to have a different first page header).

EDIT: please note my question is specifically about Word (`bookdown::word_document2`) output. The [multi-column layout instructions in the Bookdown documentation](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/multi-column.html) are for HTML and PDF output types, so do not apply to my use case.

Comment: [This may help](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/multi-column.html).

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately that appears to only work for HTML / PDF / Beamer output types, not Word.

Comment: Maybe look at the source code for `officedown::rdocx_document` and `bookdown::word_document2` (or `rmarkdown::word_document`). They may both be sending everything through Pandoc, but the former has implemented an argument that the latter hasn't.

Comment: I opened a Github Issue with this question, as a feature request, on the repo of `bookdown`. Hopefully it will be implemented (or maybe already is implemented, and we just didn't know it!) https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues/1433

Comment: update:  apparently it's not possible using pandoc. Might be better trying to get officedown to support different first page headers